# Como registrar um log através do log4net quando se utiliza o Task Scheduler para inciar um console application?

Tags: c#, log4net

Compilei um Console application em c# que possui o log4net(que ja está funcionando normalmente quando eu executo o app) e configurei através do Task Scheduler do Windows para que execute o console application todo dia X horas.

Porém quando ele executa o programa,o output do log não está sendo feito, simplesmente não loga. Gostaria de saber como faço para ele logar mesmo programado para executar automaticamente noTask Scheduler, segue o meu log4net.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<log4net>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
  </root>

  <appender name="console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <!--<conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />-->
      <conversionPattern value="%message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="file" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="logs/migracaoLog.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="false" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>  
</log4net>

</configuration>
```

Comment: esse é o arquivo de configuração da aplicação?

Comment: Não, esse é o log4net.config é o arquivo de configuração do log4net

Comment: entendi, estão será que não pode ser problema de permissão? o usuário que está setando para executa a aplicação tem permissão de escrita na pasta?

Answer (score -2):

private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
  <level value="FATAL" />
</logger>
<appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\benidesk\meusLogs\log.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```